# Why we need two conductors in a waveguide for TEM propagation?

Tags: electrical-engineering

Do the two conductors have to be separated (no current flowing) or two connected lines? Of course both connected to a generator?

Thinking about the Maxwell equations I guess the two conductors are separated so we just have a static electric field between the two pieces of metal. But if that's the case why do many figures in the books also show a magnetic field? The magnetic field for what I know can only be generated if a variable current is flowing? I am a bit confused about this topic.

Comment: [This question was cross-posted to Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/244239/82691).